# Failed to connect to Remote server

Tags: c#, .net, dns

I am unable to resolve an address to IP. It is giving an exception "No such host found". But i am able to access the same site through my web browser.

```
IPAddress address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("https:\\google.com")[0];
```

Is it because my web browser is using a proxy. How can i still connect to it? i cannot change the proxy setting of the web browser as they are by default in the my company.

Comment: Have you tried the full URL?

Comment: @NathanWhite yes, i have tried the full url. It is still not working.

Comment: Do you have to specify the https?

Comment: i have tried with https as well. Can the proxy be a problem? because in my LAN settings it shows that all connections are made through proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're including `https:\\`. I have tested the code, and it works perfectly when you just use `www.google.com` as the parameter for `Dns.GetHostAddresses()`.

Comment: not working for me though. not able to figure out the reason as well

Comment: What exactly are you using as the parameter for `Dns.GetHostAddresses()`?

Comment: IPAddress address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com")[0];

Comment: @user2038650 What proxy service are you using?

Comment: winhttp show proxy on command promt says i am not using a proxy. But my Lan settings in Internet options say i am connecting through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

```
IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com");

foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
{
    Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
}
```

As a test. Works fine.

Comment: thr is probably some problem in my network settings. this is also giving the same exception. GetHostAddress is not able to locate the host itself, whatever option i am using.